# Getting the error while inserting rows into azure table

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-powershell

I am trying to upload azure table row using PowerShell and I am receiving the below error. Could this be due to wrong Azure Storage powershell modules? I am using Azure.Storage 4.0.2 module.

Below is the Code:

```
# Getting all the resource group
$resource_group_list = Get-AzureRmResourceGroup

# Iterating through the resource group
foreach($resource_group_list_iterator in $resource_group_list){

    # Since the solution applies for virtual machines,
    # obtain the list of virtual machines for the resource group
    $virtual_machine_list = get-azurermvm -ResourceGroupName $resource_group_list_iterator.ResourceGroupName

    # Proceed only when resource group contains virtual machines
    if(!($virtual_machine_list -eq $null)){

        # Iterate through the virtual machine list
        foreach($virtual_machine_list_iterator in $virtual_machine_list){

            # Creat an unique ID by concatinating 'Resource Group name' and 'Virtual Machine name'
            $unique_id = $resource_group_list_iterator.ResourceGroupName + $virtual_machine_list_iterator.name
            #Write-Host $unique_id
            $tag_list = $virtual_machine_list_iterator.Tags

            $tag_list.GetEnumerator() | foreach {
            #write-host $_.key
            #Write-Host $_.value
            #write-host "" 

            $partitionKey1 = $unique_id

            if($_.key -eq 'owner' -and $_.value -eq 'ibm') {
                #write-host "true"
                $virtual_machine_name = $virtual_machine_list_iterator.Name.ToString()
                $virtual_machine_resource_group_name = $resource_group_list_iterator.ResourceGroupName.ToString()
                $virtual_machine_location = $virtual_machine_list_iterator.Location.ToString()
                $virtual_machine_size = $virtual_machine_list_iterator.HardwareProfile.VmSize.ToString()
                $virtual_machine_operating_system = $virtual_machine_list_iterator.StorageProfile.ImageReference.Offer.ToString()



                $hash = @{}
                #$hash.add('currentDate', $current_date)
                $hash.Add('VM Name','VM')
                $hash.Add('Resource Group',$virtual_machine_resource_group_name)
                $hash.add('Location',$virtual_machine_location)
                $hash.add('VM Size',$virtual_machine_size)
                $hash.add('Operating System',$virtual_machine_operating_system)

                Add-StorageTableRow -table $azure_table_object -partitionKey ("CA") -rowKey $unique_id -property $hash

            }
           }

        }

    }

}
```

Below is the exception that I received:

```
Exception calling "Execute" with "1" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (400) 
Bad Request."
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\AzureRmStorageTable\1.0.0.21\AzureRmStorageTableCor
eHelper.psm1:267 char:16
+ ...      return ($table.CloudTable.Execute((invoke-expression "[Microsoft ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StorageException
```

I have gone thru few online resources on how to troubleshoot, but I did not get any solution.

Comment: 400 error means that the client supplied paramters are not accepted by server. According to mentioned error, the error happened on the code line `267 char:16  return ($table.CloudTable.Execute((invoke-expression "[Microsoft...` that you are not mentioned. We could debug powershell code with [Powershell ISE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/ise/how-to-debug-scripts-in-windows-powershell-ise?view=powershell-6).

Comment: thank you Tom. The code that i provided you is all that I am running. If you can see the error, the storage cmdlet is inturn executing some code from "AzureRmStorageTableCoreHelper.psm1". How can I further de-bug this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the fiddler to catch adding entity request on my side with your code. Then I could get the detail information that *property name is invalid.*

[image]

So please have a try to change the property name with following code.

```
$hash.Add('VM_Name','VM')  #VM Name is invalid
$hash.Add('Resource_Group',$virtual_machine_resource_group_name) #Resource Group is invalid
$hash.add('Location',$virtual_machine_location)
$hash.add('VM_Size',$virtual_machine_size) #VM size is invalid
$hash.add('Operating_System',"windows")     
Add-StorageTableRow -table $table -partitionKey ("CA") -rowKey $unique_id -property $hash
```

For more information about azure table property name please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Understanding-the-Table-Service-Data-Model#property-names).

> poperty names are case-sensitive strings up to 255 characters in size. Property names should follow naming rules for [C# identifiers](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=155321).

**Test Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you Tom. I also realized that something was fishy with the property names. And that it was not expecting "spaces".